# Pandas - Replace values based on index and not in index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the sample code.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 1)), columns=list('A'))
```

I have a list dl=[0,2,3,4,7]

At the index positions specified by list, I would like to have column A as "Yes".

The following code works

```
df.loc[dl,'A']='Yes'
```

How do I fill column 'A' with 'No' for column values not in index.
Please forgive me if this is a duplicate post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `np.where`

I'm making an assumption that there is a better way to do both `'Yes'` and `'No'` at the same time.  If you truly just want to fill in the `'No'` after you've already got the `'Yes'` then refer to [Fatemehhh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348904/2336654)'s answer

```
df.loc[:, 'A'] = np.where(df.index.isin(dl), 'Yes', 'No')
```

---

#### Experimental Section

Not meant for actual suggestions

```
f = dl.__contains__
g = ['No', 'Yes'].__getitem__
df.loc[:, 'A'] = [*map(g, map(f, df.index))]

df

     A
0  Yes
1   No
2  Yes
3  Yes
4  Yes
5   No
6   No
7  Yes
8   No
9   No
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the isin function. '~' will reverse it so that the output is elements that are not in dl.

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(dl),'A']='No'
```

Answer (score 1):

First fill all rows of "A" with "No". Then update/overwrite the specific rows with "Yes".

```
df.loc[:,'A']='No'
df.loc[dl,'A']='Yes'
```

Answer (score 1):

by using the difference between the list dl and the df list itself:

```
df.iloc[list( set(df.index) - set(dl))]  = 'No'
```

or

```
df.iloc[[x for x in range(len(df)) if x not in dl]] = 'No'
```

Comment: `pandas.Index` objects already have a `difference` method.  So this should work: `df.loc[df.index.difference(dl), 'A'] = 'No'`

Comment: What's interesting is that `loc` can handle `set`s just fine.  To shorten up the syntax with a little set literal unpacking (not even sure what to call this) `df.loc[{*df.index} - {*dl}, 'A'] = 'No'`

Comment: Also, for the record, I think this is the most eloquent way of answering OP's actual question.